# when i add a reference to my project, does it bundle it together?

Tags: .net, dll

when i add a DLL to my project, and then publish it, does it add the DLL so that i dont have to worry about the reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yup, it will (by default).  It tries to make it easy for you :)

Long answer:  Should you so choose, you can choose not to copy the dll.  Also, if your reference is to the GAC, then it won't (similar to the way System dlls are handled).